# Creating a function that performs math on a given string

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

The problem is a 3 part problem which required me to make a function called addOne that took a number as it's argument and added one to it then create a function called subtractOne that took a number argument and subtracted one from it. After that I had to create a function called usePotions that took a string as it's argument and if the string had the character "A" in it, you would need to use the addOne function on the digit before "A" if it was available. If the string had the character "B" in it, you would need to use the subtractOne function on the digit before the "B" if it was available. You also want to remove the the letters from the string and just return the string with the math performed on the numbers if it was available. This is what I have so far:

```
function addOne (num) {
  num += 1;
  return num
}

function subtractOne(num1) {
  num1 -= 1;
  return num
}


function usePotions(string) {
  
  let newArray = [];
  
  
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (typeof string[i] === "A" && typeof string[i-1] === "number") {
       newArray.push(addOne(string[i-1]));
    } else if (typeof string[i] === "B" && typeof string[i-1] === "number") {
      newArray.push(subtractOne(string[i-1]));
    } else if (typeof string[i] === "number"){
        newArray.push(string[i]);
      }
}
  return newArray.join('');
}
 console.log(usePotions("3A78B51"))
```

*When I tried checking to see if the array was getting values passed into it the array remained empty and I'm not sure why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You've to rethink a part of the logic. Every character in a string is type of string, no matter it looks like a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addOne` function won't work because adding anything to a string results in a string in JS.

I.e. `'1' + 1 = '11'`. Thus you must convert the string to number before adding.

Also `typeof string[i-1]` will always return `string`. You need some other way to check that the char is a digit.

Here is your fixed code:

```js
function addOne (num) {
  return num * 1 + 1
}

function subtractOne(num) {
  return num - 1
}


function usePotions(string) {
  
  let newArray = [];
  let digit = /\d/
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === "A" && digit.test(string[i-1])) {
        newArray.pop();
        newArray.push(addOne(string[i-1]));
    } else if (string[i] === "B" && digit.test(string[i-1])) {
        newArray.pop();
        newArray.push(subtractOne(string[i-1]));
    } else if (digit.test(string[i])) {
        newArray.push(string[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return newArray.join('');
}
console.log(usePotions("3A78B51"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Ckcmoney24 welcome. If it helped, don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Question for you @Stalinko how would I modify the digit.test statement so I dont repeat the same digit I just added to (for example in this code if I wanted the return to be "47751")

Comment: @Ckcmoney24 well you'd have to change the algorithm. Simplest way which I see - just pop the last digit from `newArray` before pushing. I've updated my code.

Comment: gotcha I figured that method would end up popping out one of the characters that I actually wanted so I kind of brushed it off haha. Thank you for your help man I've been working on this for awhile and couldn't get anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your goal is the same as mine, which is to learn the intricacies of JavaScript, I've put in quite some time for you. Even though this is a late response, hopefully this will help you. (This is my first post as well!)

In regards to your code, I'm seeing a several issues:

1. The logic I see is: you are attempting to iterate through the string, checking if string[i] equals to 'A' and if the char/digit/number before it is a number. However, you are checking if `typeof string[i] === 'A'` when you should be checking `string[i] === 'A'`
2. Then, `typeof string[i-1] === "number"` will always return to false because each char/digit/number of a string is always going to default to be a string, even if it is a '3', 'A', '7', etc...
3. You are also passing in `string[i-1]`, which is also always a string, to the `addOne` and `subtractOne` functions, so the functions will not work properly. '3'+ 1 would give you '31'. Same/similar issue as point 2.
4. If we were to remove the problematic `&& typeof string[i-1] === "number"`, then we're running into issues of the other `else if`'s. In the first iteration, string[0] = '3', the code checks if '3' equals to 'A', and it does not, then it goes on to check if '3' equals to 'B', and it does not, then it checks if typeof '3' equals to a number, and it does not, so then nothing is pushed into the newArray. Nothing happens.
5. Even if I were to fix the code by taking out the `&& typeof string[i-1] === "number"`, pass in a number into `addOne` & `subtractOne`, change the `else if (typeof string[i] === "number")` to `else`, it still pushes '3' into the newArray upon the first iteration, and you'd get **3478751**. Better! I guess you could then proceed to use `.shift()` to remove that first element of the array, and then use `.join('')` to return the desired string, and this solution will work! (For some reason this approach seems a bit funny to me, though.)

While you can solve this in many different ways, if I may simplify the goals of the problem, and believe me I've really worked hard to simplify my solution as well, this is my best version with explanations. (Your addOne and subtractOne functions would work fine.)

```
// declare a function that adds 1 to a number
const addOne = function(x) { return x + 1 };

// declare a function that subtracts 1 from a number
const subtractOne = function(x) { return x - 1 };

function usePotions(string) {
  // input: string
  // output: modified string

  // iterate through the string using a for loop (for maximum flexibility)
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    // check if "next char" === 'A', this is what makes the most sense to me
    if (string[i + 1] === 'A') {
      // convert prior "char" (aka string[i]/"current char") into a number 
      // pass Number(string[i]) into addOne
      // reassign string by taking 1st part of string up to string[i], 
      // concatenating with the remainder of the string
      // starting at str[i+2] up to the end of str (removing 'A')
      string = string.slice(0, i).concat(addOne(Number(string[i])), string.slice(i + 2));
    } else if (string[i + 1] === 'B') {
      // iterate through the string, check if current "char" === 'B'
      // pass the prior "char" into subtractOne to -1 to the num before 'B'
      // modify the string just like we did for 'A' but for 'B'
      string = string.slice(0, i).concat(subtractOne(Number(string[i])), string.slice(i + 2));
    }
  }

  return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert(str){ 
  let no = parseInt(str); 
  if(isNaN(no))
    return str; 
  
  let s = str.replace(no,''); 

  let finalStr = s.startsWith("A") ? `${no+1}${s}` : `${no-1}${s}`; 

  return finalStr;

}

console.log(convert("12Bbcd"));//11Abcd
console.log(convert("12Abcd"));//13Abcd
```